# Check for presence of "builds" section in package.json using jq

Tags: json, npm, jq, npm-scripts

I need to write a shell script to check for the presence of builds key in  `package.json` file for an NPM project. For this, I'm using the `has` function of `jq`; but getting false positives. If not familiar with `package.json`, my intend is to look for the presence of a key in the JSON file, but the key is by itself a JSON object (i mean nested).

Below is the script used.

```sh
if [ $(./jq 'has(".scripts.build")' package.json) == "true" ];
then
        echo "Has a build section"
else
        echo "No build section"
fi
```

This script always hits the `else` part of the code. Can you please point out where am going wrong.

Comment: Show how your JSON looks like

Comment: `if [ "$(./jq .scripts.build package.json)" != null ]` ? `if [ "$(./jq '.scripts | has("build")' package.json)" == true ]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use the exit code with the `-e` switch for such conditionals. Furthermore, you're trying to check for the existence of a key in the object and it probably doesn't have a `".scripts.build"` property. It won't check that path like you're probably thinking. Drill down to the object first if you want to use `has/1`.

```
if ./jq -e '.scripts | has("build")' package.json > /dev/null; then
    echo "Has a build section"
else
    echo "No build section"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that package.json contains a JSON object, one can get away with the filter:

```
.scripts.build
```

For robustness, though, it might be advisable to go with: `.scripts.build?`

For example, if you wanted to find all the package.json files under the pwd that are missing .scripts.build, you could go with the strategy suggested by @JeffMercado:

```
find . -name package.json | while read f
do
  jq -e '.scripts.build?' "$f" > /dev/null || echo "$f"
done
```

Or you might be able to skip the shell test entirely, e.g. here's a better solution to the task just mentioned:

```
find . -name package.json | while read f
do
  jq -r 'select(.scripts.build? | not)
         | input_filename' "$f"
done
```